# Question on modules.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $\mathbb Z \subset A$ be integral domains. If $A$ is a finite $\mathbb Z$-module then how to show that there exist $w_1,w_2,\dots,w_n \in K$  such that $A$ is isomorphic to the subring $\mathbb Z[w_1,w_2,\dots,w_n]$ of $K$, where $K$ is the algebraic closure of $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: What is $Q$...?

Comment: Q is rational numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that finite <=> finitely generated and integral. Then $Q(A)$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$, Hence there is an embedding $Q(A) \hookrightarrow K$. The image of $A$ is finite over $\mathbb{Z}$, hence has the desired form.